# Django Dynamic Inline Formset without any fields in the parent model not working

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-forms

i am new to Django and i have been trying to create a dynamic inline form but ran into an issue. I am trying to create an inline form with user-customisable number of inline forms (models: DataSheetProperties) with foreign key to models: ProvisionalData. However, in the parent model (ProvisionalData), I do not want the user to fill in any fields, but for me to do the filling of the fields in the backend. Meaning, the user should only see the child model (DataSheetProperties) and be able to add or remove instances of that inline form as they see fit. The rendering of the form is okay, but when i press the 'save' button, I can't seem to save it and it does not even run through the form_valid() method in the views.py. I figured it was because there was no fields in the form of the parent model for the user to fill in, hence django does not recognise that the form was being submitted. Hence, I tried to add in a field into the forms.py (ProvisionalDataCreateForm) under the Div() section of the __init_ method. After adding the field, I was able to save the inline form successfully. However, I would hope that the user would not be able to see and fill in any of the fields in the parent model and form as I would want that form to be automatically filled up in the backend. Hope that you guys can help to give some suggestions, all answers are welcome. Thanks in advance!

I downloaded the django-dynamic-formset plugin from this link to use in my dynamic inline formset.
https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Also, the code for my dynamic inline formset can from this website.
https://dev.to/zxenia/django-inline-formsets-with-class-based-views-and-crispy-forms-14o6

forms.py

```
class ProvisionalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSheetProperties
        fields = ['properties', 'name','method','value','units']
        exclude = []

ProvisionalDataFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ProvisionalData, DataSheetProperties,
                                           form=ProvisionalDataForm, extra=1,
                                           can_delete=True)


class ProvisionalDataCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProvisionalData
        exclude = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProvisionalDataCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3 create-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-9'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Fieldset('Add properties',
                    Formset('data')),
                HTML("<br>"),
                ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'save')),
                )
            )
```

models.py

```
class ProvisionalData(models.Model):
    status = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactive'),
    )
    provisionaldata_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rndProject = models.ForeignKey('RndProject', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=status, default='active')
    justification = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True) 

class DataSheetProperties(models.Model):
    options = (
        ('physical','Physical'),
        ('mechanical','Mechanical'),
        ('thermal','Thermal'),
    )

    status = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactive'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Property Name')
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Test Method')
    units = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Unit of Measurement')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Typical Value')
    properties = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=options)
    data = models.ForeignKey('ProvisionalData', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=status, default='active')
```

views.py

```
class ProvisionalDataSheetView(CreateView):
    model = ProvisionalData
    form_class = ProvisionalDataCreateForm
    template_name = 'rnd/provisional_datasheet.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProvisionalDataSheetView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['data'] = ProvisionalDataFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['data'] = ProvisionalDataFormSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.rndProject = RndProject.objects.filter(rnd_project_id = self.kwargs['pk'])[0]
        context = self.get_context_data()
        data = context['data']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if data.is_valid():
                data.instance = self.object
                data.save()
        return super(ProvisionalDataSheetView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('rnd-project-details', kwargs={'pk': self.object.rndProject.rnd_project_id})
```

formset.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<table>
{{ formset.management_form|crispy }}

{% for form in formset.forms %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %} formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}">
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <td>
                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                        {{ hidden }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
            </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
<br>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="{% static 'rnd/jquery.formset.js' %}" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}').formset({
        addText: 'add another',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}',
    });
</script>
```

provisional_datasheet.html

```
{% extends 'rnd/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            Create provisional datasheet
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
             {% crispy form %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I cannot see any ```<form>``` tag ins your html

Comment: Hey did you fix this part? I'm having the similar problem the context data gives me just the first element and that is what is saved in db.